# angularjs how to retrieve data from mysql and show in ng-select and ng-options

Tags: mysql, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

i was trying to populate data in html form using ng-select and ng-options.but cannot figure it out.my code looks like this:

```
function get_areanames() {    
$qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from tbl_area');
$data = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $data[] = array(
                "areaid"            => $rows['areaid'],
                "areaname"     => $rows['areaname']
                );
}
print_r(json_encode($data));
return json_encode($data);
```

}

```
$scope.get_areanames = function($scope,$http){
 $http.get("library/function.php?action=get_areanames").success(function(data)
{
   $scope.areaname = data;  


});
}

<select class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Choose Area Name" name="areaname"  ng-model="areaname" required> <option></option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-options`, consider:

```
<select ng-options="item.areaid as item.areaname for item in areaname track by item.areaid"
        ng-model="selectedArea"
        class="form-control select2me"
        name="areaname"
        required>
     <option value="">Choose Area Name</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: hello @tom it didn't showed any output.is there anything wrong in my above code.

Comment: @SopaPipa, I don't know PHP, so I don't know if there's anything wrong there, but make sure that `data` in the `$http.get().success()` is the array of objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ng-options attribute to your select:

```
<select ng-options="areaitem.areaname for areaitem in areaname" ....
```

This will populate the options from the areaname array in your scope.